# Angular 12 component selector not showing content

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

In the image, you can see the situation of my app. Component selector showing the only URL not the content. Where am I wrong?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b1Nak.png)

server.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-server',
  template: './server.component.html'
})
export class ServerComponent {
  
}
```

server.component.html:

```
<p>The Server Component</p>
```

app.module.ts:

```
import { ServerComponent } from './server/server.component';`enter code here`

import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    ServerComponent 
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {}
```

app.component.html :

```
<h3>Im in the AppComponent</h3>
<hr>

<app-server></app-server>
```

Comment: template: './server.component.html' should be templateUrl: './server.component.html'

Comment: Thanks for the info. Problem solved. It escaped my attention. @MikeOne